# Php jquery mouse over help

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Now for some reason i can't get this code to work
When i move the mouse over < tr id='$id'> i want the #remove_$id to be showing and then hidden when the mouse is moved off

jQuery Code:

```
$(function() {

var id = this.id; 

$("tr").hover(function() {

$("#remove_" + id).show();

}, function() {

$("#remove_" + id).hide();

});

});
```

PHP CODE:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wall WHERE uid='$myid' ORDER BY id DESC") or die (mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id = $row['id'];

$uid = $row['uid'];

$fid = $row['fid'];

$action = $row['action'];


echo "< table width='467' border='0' align='left' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>

  < tr id='wall_$id'>

    < td width='18' height='25'>&nbsp;< /td>

    < td width='396' valign='top' class='txt'>RickStar has upload new photos. - < span class='comment'>

< a href='#'>Comment< /a>< /span>< br />< /td>

    < td width='53' valign='top'>< span class='txt'>

      < div id='remove_$id' class='mydiv'>Remove< /div>

    < /span>< /td>

  < /tr>

< /table>";


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your jQuery code to this:

```
$(function() {
    $("tr").hover(function() {
       var id = this.id.split('_').pop();
       $("#remove_" + id).show();
    }, function() {
       var id = this.id.split('_').pop();
       $("#remove_" + id).hide();
    });
});
```

That should do it. [Here's a working example if you need more help](http://jsbin.com/uyose).

Your code wasn't working because of two reasons:

- Setting the ID too early, outside the hover function `this` is either undefined or not what you think.
- You need to split the `<tr>`'s ID by `_` to get the actual ID and then use it to get to the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You mouse over the td, not the tr.

Comment: ? ... TR supports :hover in css and mouseover/mouseout in JS.